# How many fonts are available in Prawn?

Tags: prawn

I've been randomly trying fonts in Prawn, for Ruby.

For Example:
  Times New Roman - Yes
  Palatino Linotype - No

Is there a list of which fonts are available and which aren't?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a list of default fonts in the code, at lib/prawn/font/afm.rb (version 1.0.0.rc1):

```
module Prawn
  class Font
    class AFM < Font
      BUILT_INS = %w[ Courier Helvetica Times-Roman Symbol ZapfDingbats
                      Courier-Bold Courier-Oblique Courier-BoldOblique
                      Times-Bold Times-Italic Times-BoldItalic
                      Helvetica-Bold Helvetica-Oblique Helvetica-BoldOblique ]
```

Comment: These are the 14 *standard fonts* guaranteed to be available in all PDF readers.

Comment: Is Helvetica free to use?

Answer (score 11):

14 fonts are available by default: Courier, Helvetica, Symbol, Times and ZapfDingbats in various bold and italic forms.

In nearly every case I'd recommend using the font() method to load an external truetype font of your choosing. This has the added benefit of give you the option to use non latin characters.

Short answer: there's no list, just use TTF.

Comment: Using an embedded TTF may cause license fees, for example for Arial font families which belong to Monotype Imaging Holdings Inc.