# How do I use the Arial font with Prawn on OS X?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I'm trying to use ruby to generate a PDF using Prawn on OS X.  I have the following:

```
font 'Arial'
```

Arial is installed on my Mac.  But when I try to generate the PDF, I get the following error:

```
Prawn::Errors::UnknownFont in ProjectsController#show
Arial is not a known font.
```

How can I get this common font to work in Prawn?  In fact, almost anything other than Helvetica or Times New Roman throws this same error.  This is part of a Rails 3.2 app.

If I try to load the font ttf file directly, per Ashish's suggestion below, I get a `Bad font family` message:

```
RuntimeError (Bad font family):
  app/pdfs/quote_sheet_pdf.rb:29:in `page_top'
  app/pdfs/quote_sheet_pdf.rb:12:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:9:in `new'
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in show'
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:7:in `show'
  config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:7:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

Comment: Prawn has a small set of fonts, and they are embedded in the gem. Here's a [list of the available fonts](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/tree/master/data/fonts). I don't think prawn can use fonts installed in the OS.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you’re using the `:style` option to calls to `text`, e.g.

```
text "Hello World", :style => :italic
```

Then the font you’re using at the time needs to have an associated font family, otherwise you’ll get the “Bad font family” error you’re seeing, e.g. this:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("output.pdf") do
  font "/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf"
  text "Hello World", :style => :italic
end
```

produces: `Bad font family (RuntimeError)`.

One way round this would be to always specify the exact font file you want every time you want to change style, e.g.

```
font "/Library/Fonts/Arial Italic.ttf"
text "Hello World"
```

A better option would be to create a font family with the styles you want:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("output.pdf") do

  font_families.update("Arial" => {
    :normal => "/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf",
    :italic => "/Library/Fonts/Arial Italic.ttf",
    :bold => "/Library/Fonts/Arial Bold.ttf",
    :bold_italic => "/Library/Fonts/Arial Bold Italic.ttf"
  })

  font "Arial"
  text "Hello World"
  text "Hello World", :style => :italic
  text "Hello World", :style => :bold
  text "Hello World", :style => :bold_italic
end
```

After you’ve set up the font family you can just use `Arial` as the font name, and you can use the different styles easily.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem trying to load fonts like this.

```
@pdf.font_families.update(
    'Arial' => { :normal => Rails.root.join('public/arial.ttf'),
                 :bold   => Rails.root.join('public/arialbd.ttf') }
)
```

It turn's out that Rails.root.join doesn't return explicit String object. The solution is to add to_s at the end of the expression.

```
@pdf.font_families.update(
  'Arial' => { :normal => Rails.root.join('public/arial.ttf').to_s,
               :bold   => Rails.root.join('public/arialbd.ttf').to_s }
)
```

by
TheR

Answer (score 4):

try passing full path of arial.ttf to the font function as below -

```
Prawn::Document.generate("custom_font_usage.pdf") do
  font "/path/to/fonts/arial.ttf"
  text "this is a test " * 20 
end
```

Also see some links that are relevant -

1. [How many fonts are available in Prawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599904/how-many-fonts-are-available-in-prawn)
2. Prawn documentation - http://rubydoc.info/gems/prawn/0.12.0/frames

Comment: Passing the full path to the ttf file doesn't seem to work.  I just get a `Bad font family` error.

Comment: please post complete error trace. and also did you try with any other "ttf" file?

Comment: The Verdana.ttf file also failed with same message.